# Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus on second derivatives

Tags: calculus

I encountered the following question:

Find, 
$$ 
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\int_{0}^{x}\left(\int_{1}^{\sin(t)}\sqrt{1+u^4}\,du\right)dt
$$

I attempted to evaluate the above using FTC twice, however, I don't think that purely applying FTC twice is a legal  method since the derivative is twice with respect to $x$.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first derivative indeed works with FTC. Do that, now we've got:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{\sin(x)}\sqrt{1 + u^4} du$$
Let $f(u)$ be an anti-derivative of $\sqrt{1+u^4}$, such that $f'(u) = \sqrt{1+u^4}$. Then this integral can be written as: 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{\sin(x)}f'(u) du$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}[f(\sin(x)) - f(1)]$$
$$=f'(\sin(x))\cos(x)$$
$$=\cos(x)\sqrt{1+\sin^4(x)}$$
The above method works for any "FTC-like" problems where the upper and lower bounds are part of the derivative.